# Sum the values ​of a column with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python, I would like to read a column of values ​​from a csv file and add them together, but only those to the left of the ","
My csv File:

```
Name     Code  
Angel    19;90
Eduardo  20;21
Miguel   30;45
```

I would like to be able to sum only the numbers to the left of the "Code" column, so that my output is "19+20+30 = 69".
I tried deleting the ";" and converting the string to int but sums but joins the numbers together and I have this output:

```
Your final sum is : 1990 +2021 +3045 = 7056
```

Comment: expected ouput is `69` ? Or `7056` ?

Comment: output is 69, @jezrael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If need sum values before `;` use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with casting to integers and then `sum`:

```
out = df['Code'].str.extract('(.*);', expand=False).astype('int').sum()
```

Or use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select first values of lists by `str[0]`:

```
out = df['Code'].str.split(';').str[0].astype('int').sum()
```

If need sum all values create DataFrame by `expand=True` and summing first per rows and then `Series`:

```
out = df['Code'].str.split(';', expand=True).astype('int').sum().sum()
```

If need sum without `;` use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
out = df['Code'].str.replace(';','', regex=True).astype('int').sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like that:

```js
import csv

sum = 0
with open("data.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader) # skip header row
    for row in reader:
        code_values = row[1].split(";")
        for value in code_values:
            sum += int(value)

print(sum)
```

In line with "split" you can do any kind of splitting logic.

Comment: I tried this code but it gives me the following error :IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

Just modified `ZsoltB`'s answer :

```
import csv

sum = 0
with open("demo.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader) # skip header row
    for row in reader:
        code_values = row[1].split(";")
        print(code_values[0])
        sum += int(code_values[0])

print(sum)
```

The code_values[0] will ensure that you add values only from the left column.

Comment: This code takes the data by row, I need it to add by column

Comment: You want to add 19 + 20 + 30 right ?

Comment: yes, yep, correct

Comment: The above code does the same. I created a demo.csv file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a *calculation* thing, here is an approach with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) :

```
import numpy as np
​
d = {"left": 0, "right": 1}
choice = "left" # <- choose the position here
​
arr = np.genfromtxt("jacket.csv", delimiter=",", # <- specify a sep
                     dtype=None, skip_header=1, encoding=None)
​
left_vals = np.array([int(code.split(";")[d[choice]]) for code in arr[:,1]])
​
out = np.sum(left_vals)
```

Output :

```
print(out)
#69
```

Comment: Hi @Timeless, i try your code and i have this error : IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Comment: AFK now, let me check that later ;). Anyways, for the sample you shared, the code should work.